# CyanogenMod: Translate a Project

Tags: android, localization, translation, cyanogenmod

I have translated a project in CyanogenMod (the Email app) to Hebrew by adding a values-he folder, and compiled the entire repository (make). I have made sure that the full languages make file includes the *Hebrew* language.

However, when I loaded the update zip to the phone and switched the language to Hebrew, I still received the English strings. I'm pretty sure I am missing a step.

Any idea, please?

EDIT: Again, my phone supports Hebrew - as evident by other applications that do switch locale according to the values-he folder content. It's just for the Email application that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [ISO 639](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php), **he** is the correct ISO 639-1 code for the hebrew language.  Whereas [**iw** was deprecated](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_changes.php) back in 1989.  The reason some Android devices use **iw** is thanks to Sun, you can [read the details](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3639).

Devices like the Nexus S, sold in the US use **iw**.  If you go to Israel and check the locale on a phone sold there (Galaxy S for example), the language will most likely be reported as "He IL N/A עברית", so it correctly uses **he** and not the deprecated **iw**.

If you want to support this fully, you should include both variations to account for these differences.

Comment: is there a way to avoid duplicate files by linking one folder to the other? or supporting more than one language in the `values` folder?

Comment: Appreciate your answer really helpful

Comment: I think that starting from some Android version, all use "iw" instead of "he". Even the IDE started telling to use "iw" instead. Do you know from which Android version has it begun?

Comment: I tried creating a symbolic link from `values-iw` to `values-he` and it seems to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

The reason this is happening is that Android is following legacy Java local codes: Hebrew is locale IW - not HE. Change it and it will likely work. Hope this is useful for someone who finds this question ...

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your phone locale is not set to use Hebrew. In that case, the default values folder is used. You may have success with removing strings.xml (and whatever else shares a name that is contained in the values-he) from the non-Hebrew values folder.

Comment: I set my phone manually to the Hebrew locale, using the "set a language" menu option. I know it is set correctly, because the ADW application strings are in Hebrew. However, this doesn't work for Email or other applications.

Comment: Try deleting all other `values-XX` folders, except make sure that you don't delete `'colors.xml'`, `'donottranslate.xml'` or similar files in the default values folder. Just delete `strings.xml`.

Comment: I don't want to make the application Hebrew exclusive :-)