# App not using the loacal resource it needs

Tags: android, string, local

I am trying to get my app to use a different String for hebrew.
what I did was I created a different filder in "res" calles "values-iw" and places a "strings.xml" file in there.

when i do `Locale.getDefault();` i get "heb-il" which by google is ok "Java uses several deprecated two-letter codes. The Hebrew ("he") language code is rewritten as "iw".
but when I am doing `getResources().getString(R.string.deafult_sleeping);` I am getting the default string and not the one in "values-iw".
Why is that?+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Devices still use "he". I think alot of Android uses "he" and it is mapped to "iw" in the compiler. You should make both Folders to be safe.

Ps. you can check which Code you are getting with

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

Also see [Locale code for Hebrew / Reference to other locale codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202406/locale-code-for-hebrew-reference-to-other-locale-codes)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help sombody with changes of Local:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals(new Locale("he").getLanguage())
```