# Changing input language to Hebrew

Tags: java, swing, locale, jtextfield, input-language

I have a Java application with some `JTextFields` in it and I want the default language to be Hebrew.

I tried setting JVM argument(`-Duser.language=he`), I tried setting locale to hebrew:

```
TextFields[ i ].setLocale( new Locale("he"));
```

Locale changed all right - but input language doesnt change.

The only thing that worked was to change default input language through `SystemParametersInfo` which change system language. Is there any other way?

Comment: I think "iw" instead of "he". Hebrew, Israel, iw_IL: [More here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html#util-text).  Also read the javadoc on [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) about -D settings for user.language, user.region, user.country, user.variant

Comment: Also try `new Locale("he", "IL")`, as suggested [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html).

Comment: I think it doent matter "he" or "iw" - it changes automatically. I tried new Locale("he", "IL") - doesnt work.

Comment: I've recently answered a related question on the Hebrew locale. The behavior seems to had been changed with Java 17. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202406/locale-code-for-hebrew-reference-to-other-locale-codes/70882234#70882234